# Not able to install lxml verison 3.3.5 in ubuntu

Tags: python, lxml, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl python package in my application. I am getting the following message when using the same.

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/**init**.py:31:
>   UserWarning: The installed version of lxml is too old to be used with
>   openpyxl
>
> warnings.warn("The installed version of lxml is too old to be used with openpyxl")

Openpyxl requires lxml version 3.2.5 or above, and the version in my machine is 3.2.0. When I try to upgrade lxml to the latest version ie
3.3.5, it is getting interrupted with the following message.

```
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/etree.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

  Rolling back uninstall of lxml

  Replacing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml
  Replacing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml-3.2.0.egg-info
Cleaning up...

  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ov0PUy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
```

I need help in resolving the issue.

PS:- I have already installed lxml dependent packages python-dev, libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev in my machine.

Comment: Note, lxml is actually only required for tests but I think we need to check handling of whether it's there or not better. I'd advise always using a virtualenv so that you decide whether you want lxml or not. Currently, it looks like lxml is slower for reading files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're missing is zlib1g-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Running above command will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your recommendation solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade lxml
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu (and other Debian derivatives), before you build some piece of software, ensure that its build dependencies are installed. Using your example, run this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-lxml
```

That is likely going to require a whole bunch of packages, one of which is **zlib1g-dev**, [as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23571054).